# Resignation when manager is on leave

Tags: resignation, notice-period

I have recently found a new job and I need to start in a month in a half.  I need to give 30 days notice to resign, which would be in the next week (I planned it all out so that I have enough time to relocate to a new city, etc.)

My manager, whom is also the CEO of the company, announced today that he is going on leave for the next two weeks.

Is it professional to resign in this period through e-mail?

Comment: Surely your manager has appointed a lieutenant to make daily decisions while he is away.  That is your point-of-contact, now.

Comment: @WesleyLong nope, he didn't.  This is a very small company.  
There is a lack of leadership and structure (one of the reasons I am moving on).  
So I guess an e-mail would be the best?  I also did check he never added his leave to the calendar, so it wasn't common knowledge until yesterday.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not responsible for your manager being on leave. Resign politely via e-mail, possibly telling him you regret you have to do this by email and offering a phone call at his conveniance.

Comment: I generally agree with this, though I do believe if the OP can meet with their boss before he goes on leave, that would be better.

Comment: Sure. But what I understood from his post was this wasn't an option

Comment: Also - if the boss has nominated a deputy in his absence, visit the deputy personally and resign there as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't reach your manager, find out who he has asked to handle personnel issues during his absence, and contact them. If he hasn't designated a locum, his bad; contact HR and do it through them.

Comment: It's possible that if the CEO is the OP's direct manager, the company might be so small that there is no HR department nor indeed anyone senior to handle the issue in his absence. If this is indeed the case, you're just going to have to interrupt his holiday, call his mobile, and tell him you're resigning. Anyone who is CEO of such a small company will be accustomed to the fact that they can never *truly* go on leave.

Comment: @Carson63000 Yes, this is indeed the case.

Answer (score -1):

My advice is, first, try to reach your manager before he is on holiday. If you can't then try to reach him by phone and then by email.

Finally if all of this fail and if you are unable to reach your boss, then explain to him that you are really sorry but you tried all of this and you had to give your letter to the human resources as you had no choice.

This will show to your current employer that you are professional with the correct etiquette.

Comment: why would you even vaguely want to irritate your new employer to satisfy the old one? this doesn't show professionalism, it shows insanity.