# Is this enough to submit a leave notice when I did not sign any contract?

Tags: professionalism, united-states, notice-period, resignation

So I am in Michigan USA and I have been with this company for 8 months by now and when I started, I did not sign any contract, I only signed the W2 Tax Forms. They showed me the Employment Handbook and it says notice should be two weeks.

I am planning to send this email to the two presidents of the company:

> Good morning,
>
> Please consider this as my leaving notice since my manager HisName is traveling and not available in office. I am writing to inform you that I am resigning from MyPosition for CompanyName within the next two weeks.
>
> Let me know what do you
>   need from me as I do not want to leave my
>   team without sharing my knowledge with them.
>
> Please and thanks.
>
> Regards,
>   MyName

Am I doing it right?

Comment: Do you know what date will be your last day working for them? If so, then you should state that in your letter. If not, then your letter should indicate that you will work with them to decide on a final date. If it is less than two weeks, be prepared to discuss why.

Comment: If you didn't sign a contract, then notice is not technically required, though it would be unprofessional not to give them two weeks.

Comment: @KentAnderson no I don't have other plans amd I just want to leave as soon as possible. Why would I have to discuss why? I would want to say I have personal issues and maybe I will mention that I am stressed. Do you think that is not proper? They did not treat me well btw (it is of course what I think)

Comment: Why don't you just talk to your boss and give her/him your notice?

Comment: @WorkerDrone because I want to keep a record.

Comment: @SandraK - so follow up your discussion with an email, and print it out.

Comment: @WorkerDrone Well one of the presidents (two) is my boss and he is traveling now. Should I skype with him still?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Good tips here to help: http://www.wikihow.com/Write-a-Two-Weeks-Notice

Comment: remove "out of morals and respect " doesnt make sense

Comment: Also relevant: [Resignation when manager is on leave](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/34335/resignation-when-manager-is-on-leave)

Comment: Quitting without something else lined up can make it much more difficult to find the next job unless you are in a field where there are more jobs than people.

Comment: I am so sorry @HLGEM that I have to do this. I am not happy but I am stressed and will not find another job (better) if I stayed here. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sandra, maybe you really hate these people, or are simply a *very* blunt person, but that's a pretty terrible way to part ways with an employer.

First of all, it's unprofessional to quit via an e-mail when you work in the same office as your boss.

Second, that e-mail is borderline hostile, and basically says "I'd walk out today, but out of respect for my coworkers, not you, I will work another 2 weeks". You can certainly be unpleasant to them, but I don't think that leaving an e-mail record of that lying around is wise.

So instead, write a more pleasant letter, ask to speak with your on-site manager, and present it to him in person. Then e-mail the same letter to both your bosses, and leave it at that.

For example:

> Dear Management, 
> It has been a pleasure working with you, and the CompanyName team for the past X month/years, but the time has come for me to move on and pursue my personal career goals.
> I am therefore resigning my position, effective October the 21st, 2016. This letter serves as my two weeks’ notice, with my last working day being October the 21st. 
>  I wish to make a smooth transition, and will work with management and the team in order to make sure that a complete knowledge transfer of my tasks, responsibilities, and projects is accomplished before this date. ...

Comment: Good sample letter. I would only suggest, since OP as commented that they have not treated her well and it hasn't been a pleasure, that the first sentence simply start with "The time has come for me to move on and pursue..."

Comment: @KentAnderson - I don't think I'm going to update the answer, for the following reasons: the OP didn't include the "didn't treat me well" info in her main question. It's bad form to include additional info in the comments and not update the question as some (such as myself) might not read the entire comment thread to glean those nuggets of information. Also, this was not meant to be a sample that she can simply copy outright, but a starting point for her to build on.

Comment: I did not edit and include that in my answer, since my mind is not set with that fact. That's not the reason (or the biggest reason) of why I am leaving. So I don't want anyone to take it into consideration. I almost copied the letter in this answer as is and will go with my copy that has a reason of leaving and with more sweet words and thankful statements. Plus that I spoke personally with the manager that is here and will follow with an email to my direct manager. Thank you for your help.